# PHP - best way to copy remote file to local filesystem

Tags: php

I have large (6MB currently, keeps getting bigger) xml file on remote server, which I'm using frequently on server.

Downloading it to server every time would take a lots of time, so I'm copying it to local file.

Currently, I'm using `file_get_contents` and `file_put_contents` to do so, but that means that whole file must be loaded to memory.

**Is there anything like** `readfile` **, that would just directly stream that xml file to a file on my server?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$remote = fopen('http://...', 'r');
$local  = fopen('myfile.xml', 'w');

stream_copy_to_stream($remote, $local);
```

See http://php.net/stream_copy_to_stream. The simpler alternative would actually be to use [`copy`](http://php.net/copy).

If at all possible, you may want to use [rsync](http://rsync.samba.org) instead though, which could make this a whole lot more efficient by transferring only the differences between the two files. I'd set up rsync using a cron job instead of doing this in PHP.

Comment: Thanks, in the end, I used copy. Did some benchmarks and stream_copy_to_stream seemed to be cca. 1 second slower then copy (on this particular file).